# bug when removing rows from a pandas multindex?

Tags: pandas, indexing

I was playing around with data I had which is a deep multindex with only one 'value' column.  I removed some of the rows which were bad data but then had trouble with indexing stuff...  Any ideas?

initialize example dataframe (not my data):

```
m=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [sorted(i) for i in [['one','two'],'abcd']],
    names=['nums','lets'])
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(m)),index=m)
```

which creates

```
nums lets          
one  a     0.433026
     b     1.203037
     c    -0.965066
     d     1.028274
two  a     0.228630
     b     0.445138
     c    -1.136602
     d     0.135137
```

followed by (to remove bad data)

```
df2=df1.loc[
    ~((df1.index.get_level_values('nums')=='two')
    &(df1.index.get_level_values('lets')=='c'))]
```

this only removes 'two c':

```
nums lets          
one  a     0.433026
     b     1.203037
     c    -0.965066
     d     1.028274
two  a     0.228630
     b     0.445138
     d     0.135137
```

here things start to get buggy.

```
df2.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,'c']]
```

fails which is annoying and unexpected but OK.
but then why does

```
df2.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,'a']]
```

fail?  The error returned is 
KeyError: 'the label [a] is not in the [columns]'

Even weirder -

```
df2.loc[pd.IndexSlice['two','a']]
```

is perfectly fine.

I'm using the latest anaconda so pandas  0.14.1
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers)

you are violating the usage of IndexSlice - this is clearly explained in the warning box